# Creating database from device_id and device_token. Which component is unique device ID or device token?

Tags: android, ios, database, mobile, window

> Suppose I have two different Apps A and B.

If I install both apps on `IOS, Android, Window mobile`. After install,
then I have uninstall these app then reinstall on IOS, Android and Window mobile then `which component is unique device ID or device token`?

```
A and B:
IOS: device ID or device token??
Android: device ID or device token??
Window: device ID or device token??
```

> How can I distinguish A and B Apps install unique on each device?

I am creating database:

```
id, platform ( 1=> android,2=> ios, 3 => window), request_coming_from ( A=> A app, B=> B app), device_id, device_token, created,modified

1, 1, A, ????, ???? , 2016-07-07 12:02:34,2016-07-07 12:02:34
2, 1, B, ????, ???? , 2016-07-07 12:02:34,2016-07-07 12:02:34
3, 2, A, ????, ???? , 2016-07-07 12:02:34,2016-07-07 12:02:34
4, 2, B, ????, ???? , 2016-07-07 12:02:34,2016-07-07 12:02:34
5, 3, A, ????, ???? , 2016-07-07 12:02:34,2016-07-07 12:02:34
6, 3, B, ????, ???? , 2016-07-07 12:02:34,2016-07-07 12:02:34
```

Everytime Apps open on each device it will hit an API and from it 
I will store platform,request_coming_from,device_id,device_token and created and modified date is of current date-time of the system.

`If you have any idea and effective way to store device_id and device_token in database?`

> So that after I can calculate how many nuumber of mobiles apps (A & B)
>   install on different mobile ( not same mobile.)
>
> Example:

```
Mobile (M1 - android):



A is install

Mobile (M2 - ios)

A is install 
B is install


Mobile (M3 - ios)

B is install

Mobile (M4 - window)

B is install
```

> Output:

```
A => 
      1=> android
      1=> ios 

B=>
    2 => ios
    1=> window
```

Answer (score 0):

use Android id as unique value

```
String androidId = Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), "android_id");
```

check this for more info..

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html